# Remote debugging JavaScript Azure Functions

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

Is there any tooling available to debug Javascript Azure Functions remotely in Visual Studio or VSCode? I'm using Visual Studio - Version 15.7.2 and latest VSCode. I also have installed Azure Functions core tools but that helps with local debugging/development only.

Attach debugger works fine for C# functions but for JavaScript. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: If your function is HTTP triggered just use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and run the function locally, it's much easier to see what's up.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to remote debug javaScript functions currently

Answer (score 0):

Now i think they have give experimental feature of remote debugging for azure function on typescript , you can read about this more on Features section on github https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions